# Multi-value Table in SQL does not have enough columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, when I have a multi-value table that is the languages a person can speak. There are, let's say, 5 columns for storing the languages.

```
CREATE TABLE Languages  
(  
    PersonID int primary key,  //this is FOREIGN KEY to a Person, "REFERENCES Person(ID)" for example
    Lang1 varchar(30),  
    Lang2 varchar(30),  
    Lang3 varchar(30),  
    Lang4 varchar(30),  
    Lang5 varchar(30)  
)
```

What are the solutions if there is someone who can speak more than 5 languages?

Comment: Thank you, but I already see that, I just simply write one table of the Languages a person can speak here. But my question is that what to do if a person can speak more than there are columms in the Language table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is broken and cannot handle the scenario you describe. You need to fix the design, the normal design for this situation would be:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID int identity (1,1) primary key,
    Forename varchar(128),
    Surname varchar(128)
    -- etc etc
)

CREATE TABLE Language
(
    LanguageID int primary key,
    [Name] varchar(128)
    -- etc etc
)

CREATE TABLE PersonLanguage
(
    -- Optional to have a specific PK for a linking table - I prefer to
    PersonLanguageID int identity (1,1) primary key,
    PersonID int foreign key reference Person (PersonId),
    LanguageID int foreign key reference Language (LanguageId)
)
```

Then you can add as many languages as you like e.g.

```
-- First insert will give ID 1
insert into Person (Forename, Surname)
values ('Bob', 'Test');

-- Insert will give IDs 1-7
insert into Language ([Name])
values ('English'), ('Spanish'), ('French'), ('German'), ('Dutch'), ('Portuguese'), ('Greek');

-- Add as many languages as you like
insert into PersonLanguage (PersonId, LanguageId)
values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7);
```